# How to attach array in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have returned this format of data

```
{
    "stations": [
        {
            "get_off": "sahayoginagar",
            "get_on": "kanti",
            "station_list": [
                "values1",
                "values2",
                "values3",
                "values4",
                "values5",
                "values6",

            ],
            "v_type": "micro"
        }
    ]
```

I can get the value of stations , but how to get the value of station_list

I have used this logic inside onBindViewHolder but it only outputs last value!

```
 for(String hello : station.getSt_List()){
            holder.station_name.setText(hello);
        }
}
```

I am very much beginner in Android and also in Programming! Can somebody help me!

```
This is my adapter class: 
public class StationsRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StationsRecycleViewAdapter.StationViewHolder>{

    List<Station> example;
    List<Stations> stationList;
    Stations station;
    List links;
    Stations ss;
    Station s;

    public class StationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView station_name;

        public StationViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
                station_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
        }
    }

    public StationsRecycleViewAdapter(List<Stations> stationList){
        this.stationList = stationList;
    }

    @Override
    public StationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_station, parent,false);
        return new StationViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StationViewHolder holder, int position) {

System.out.println("1");
        //s = example.get(position);

        station = stationList.get(position);

        System.out.println("Found ASrray" + station.getSt_List());
        System.out.println("Found or Not" + stationList.size() + station.getGet_on() + station.getGet_off());
        System.out.println("2");
        String str="";
        for(String hello : station.getSt_List()){

            // added \n here

            System.out.println("3");
            str+=hello+",\n";
        }

        // EDIT
        System.out.println("4");
        holder.station_name.setText(str);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stationList.size();
    }
}
```

[Please take a look a this pic.. I want this kind of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M556D.png)

[Result i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJm07.jpg)

for creating circle i have done this in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/station_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sahayoginagar"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"

            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post code properly first

Comment: I have added my adapter class! can u please take a look ! Thank you

Comment: I want to set text those arrays : "values1",
                "values2",
                "values3",
                "values4",
                "values5",
                "values6",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StationViewHolder holder, int position) {

    System.out.println("1");

    station = stationList.get(position);

    System.out.println("Found ASrray" + station.getSt_List());
    System.out.println("Found or Not" + stationList.size() + station.getGet_on() + station.getGet_off());

    //MADE CHANGES HERE 

    String str="";
    for(String hello : station.getSt_List()){

        // added \n here ADDED CODE HERE FOR BULLET

        str+= Html.fromHtml("\u2022")+" "+ hello+",\n";
    }

    // EDIT

    holder.station_name.setText(str);



}
```

Not need of having a `for` loop remove it. I think this will help..!!

Comment: **station.getSt_List()** this one is red underlined!! says; cannot resolve method toString(List<String>)

Comment: not working mns you are having any error ?? or the solution is not what you needed?

Comment: Yess it workss! But there is problem! I need to show dots in every individual items but only single dot is showing!! Look at my edit post for the result i got

Comment: From this code you can not add a green circle in front of every station as there is only ONE `textview` and ONE `imageview`. This is possible if you display the station_list in some other `recycleview` or `listview`. There is one way i can suggest you can have bullets instead of this Image.!!

Comment: see my EDIT.. I have added some code for bullet.. hope that helps you :)

Comment: Happy coding..!! :). I suggest you delete extra comments from the answer.. so it could be helpful to others..!!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Looking at your example screenshot you need a textview on top of your screen to display station general info. Below that you'll need your RecyclerView displaying the station names.

The solution will look like this.

Modify your adapter class like this. It won't need to know anything about the station object itself. You only need to pass a list of the station names.

```
public class StationsRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StationsRecycleViewAdapter.StationViewHolder>{

    List<String> stationList;

    public class StationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView station_name;

        public StationViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            station_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
        }
    }

    public StationsRecycleViewAdapter(List<String> stationList){
        this.stationList = stationList;
    }

    @Override
    public StationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_station, parent,false);
        return new StationViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.station_name.setText(stationList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stationList.size();
    }
}
```

In your calling Activity/Fragment you'll instantiate your adapter like this and set the general station information.

```
Stations station = stations.get(index); // get the station you want to display
textViewGeneralInfo.setText(String.format("Get up at %s and get off at %s", station.getGet_on() + station.getGet_off());
StationRecycleViewAdapter adapter = new StationRecycleViewAdapter(station.getSt_List());
```

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Your layout will look like this.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGeneralInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since position is only 1! it only prints one value! I have tried it! Thank you for your reply

Comment: position is set of stations not stations_list! So position holds only 1 value

Comment: What are you trying to show in a list here. Are you showing rows of Stations or rows of Station_List ?

Comment: i need to show both rows of stations and rows of stations_list! problem is i cannot get the rows of stations_list!

Comment: Can you show an example of the exact data that should be displayed in the first 2 rows?

Comment: I have posted Picture above please take a look at that picture! I think you will be clear from that picture

Comment: Thanks, and is there only one station (like row 1) displayed on one screen at a time or can there be more?

Answer (score 0):

Make a POJO or MODEL class for JSON. [Go to this site.](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Parse the Data set it in List Model class Pass them in Model Constructor and After complete Parsing and Saving data in Model. Pass the Model in `OnBindHolder`. Get the Data from List Model which was pass from activity or Fragment.

Comment: I have used that link!! I have posted picture above.. please take a look at it! i think you will understand more from it